# Sawtooth transaction payload decode

Tags: hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-sawtooth

I fired one transaction on Sawtooth. I can see transaction data using API. My question is how to decode the transaction payload.

```
{
      "header": {
        "batcher_public_key": "03d58421f80cf7f2d51efd7f4fc28fd07a81de146f7d01acc70c9e5dcfdf2cc20f",
        "dependencies": [],
        "family_name": "document",
        "family_version": "1.0",
        "inputs": [
          "7d5acb"
        ],
        "nonce": "",
        "outputs": [
          "7d5acb"
        ],
        "payload_sha512": "9be6b4029768c2dda71b86eed2b1ba441442ec56714b863993f12aeab09242ef84087bc53b0cfadb93bbf99bcc7cdb8e03d71b1158887c8c3735abafb9765a43",
        "signer_public_key": "03d58421f80cf7f2d51efd7f4fc28fd07a81de146f7d01acc70c9e5dcfdf2cc20f"
      },
      "header_signature": "e4379a4a4f66c52677df299ddc136a968efb64fba9de30acdf230a719442cdc56c2cf55953c14bbc5cc68991a8bef156df3d32fcf6c37f201c279f6ad7065cab",
      "payload": "o2RWZXJiY3NldGROYW1leCBlZjlkMThjZGIwYjNkZDNmNWU1ZWE2MDliZjY3MDhmOWVWYWx1ZWA="
    }
```

I want to decode payload": `"o2RWZXJiY3NldGROYW1leCBlZjlkMThjZGIwYjNkZDNmNWU1ZWE2MDliZjY3MDhmOWVWYWx1ZWA=".`
Can anyone please guide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sawtooth rest-api returns base64 encoded data, First you have to decode your Data,

```
    import base64
    decoded = base64.b64decode("o2RWZXJiY3NldGROYW1leCBlZjlkMThjZGIwYjNkZDNmNWU1ZWE2MDliZjY3MDhmOWVWYWx1ZWA=")
```

Now it really depends how you encoded your data, Use deserialisation for  cbor, protobuf etc.